# How to place custom lightning button in Standard button division?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have used a lightning button in the component. I have to use both SUBMIT and Cancel Buttons. But Already Cancel Button Popping up. Either I have to remove the Cancel button and add Custom Cancel button also Or I have to place Submit button beside the standard cancel button

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction"
            access="global"
            controller="P2EcdependentPicklist_NewRFI">
<!-- call doInit function on component load -->  
<aura:handler name="init" value="this" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

   <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
   <aura:attribute name="recordtypevalu" type="string" />

<!-- aura attributes-->  
<aura:attribute name="listControllingValues" type="list" default="[]" description="to store controller field values"/>
<aura:attribute name="listDependingValues" type="list" default="['--- None ---']" description="to store dependent field values"/>
<aura:attribute name="depnedentFieldMap" type="map" description="map to store dependent values with controlling value"/>
<aura:attribute name="bDisabledDependentFld" type="boolean" default="true"/> 

<aura:attribute name="objDetail" type="contact" default="{'sobjectType' : 'case'}"/>
<aura:attribute name="controllingFieldAPI" type="string" default="RFI_Type__c" description="store field API name of Controller field"/>
<aura:attribute name="dependingFieldAPI" type="string" default="RFI_SubType__c" description="store field API name of dependent field"/>

<!--Controller Field-->
<lightning:layoutItem size="12" padding="around-small">    
    <lightning:select name="controllerFld"
                      value="{!v.objDetail.RFI_Type__c}"
                      label="RFI Type"
                      onchange="{!c.onControllerFieldChange}" aura:id="RFITypeValue" required="true" messageWhenValueMissing="Choose RFI Type Value!">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.listControllingValues}" var="val">
            <option value="{!val}">{!val}</option>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>
</lightning:layoutItem>

<!--Dependent Field-->
<lightning:layoutItem size="12" padding="around-small">
    <lightning:select name="dependentFld"
                      value="{!v.objDetail.RFI_SubType__c}"
                      label="RFI SubType"
                      disabled="{!v.bDisabledDependentFld}" required="true" messageWhenValueMissing="Choose RFI SubType Value!">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.listDependingValues}" var="val" >
            <option value="{!val}">{!val}</option>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>
</lightning:layoutItem>
<c:liu_NewRFIOnOpportunity aura:id="childCmp"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put a custom button on your component along with the standard `Cancel` button as in your screenshot. The reason why the `Cancel` button is in there is because you are using [`force:lightningQuickAction`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:lightningQuickAction/documentation) interface here.

> When used as actions, components that implement the `force:lightningQuickAction` interface display in a panel with standard action controls, such as a **Cancel** button. These components can display and implement their own controls in the body of the panel, but can’t affect the standard controls.

---

To resolve this (and how I have done in past), you should instead use [`force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader/documentation). This will ensure that the standard actions are not displayed.

> When used as actions, components that implement the `force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader` interface display in a panel without additional controls.

You may though need to provide a custom `Cancel` action for Users.